# Can an Arduino and an NI USB-6009 DAQ board interfere with each other's signals when they are simultaneously reading signals from different sensors?

Tags: communication

Hello dear Arduino SE community.

I have 5 sensors. I read 4 of them with an NI USB-6009 DAQ board and I read the fifth one with an Arduino UNO R3. Though, with the fifth sensor not only I read a signal from it, but I also send a signal to it.

Both the Arduino and the NI board are connected to a computer via two different USB ports and send the signals to the computer simultaneously. Also - simultaneously - the Arduino sends a signal to the fifth sensor.

I noticed a strange behavior with the signal from one of the sensors read by the NI board. It starts with giving me a signal that is clearly wrong and over the course of, approximately, 5 minutes gradually changes to a correct reading.

That hadn't happened when I didn't have Arduino connected to the computer at the same time.

Thus, I'm wondering if it is possible that an Arduino and an NI board can interfere with each other's signals when connected to the computer simultaneously. If it is possible, is it something widespread and is there a working solution?

Thank you in advance.
Ivan

P.S. I deliberately don't provide the specs of my system because the point of my question is not to resolve the issue but to learn if what I described is possible theoretically and if such cases have been encountered.

Comment: anything is possible ... please ask a focused question that is actually answerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem.

The sensor that was giving me the wrong signal was plugged to the same electrical circuit with "heavy" equipment (two DC laboratory power supplies). It is well known that one shouldn't do it because "heavy" equipment sends noise back to the circuit which, ultimately, causes noise in the signal generated by the sensor.

Thus, my issue had nothing to do with the Arduino interfering with the USB-6009 through the computer.

To make sure, I disconnected the Arduino from the computer and still got the same wrong signal from the problematic sensor. Then, I plugged the problematic sensor to another electrical circuit, connected the Arduino back to the computer and got the right signal.

Thus, I conclude that one can safely use an Arduino and a USB-6009 with the same computer.